# UI router - How do i create a nested state

Tags: angular-ui-router

I have a state as the following:

```
.state('main', {url: '/main', templateUrl: 'views/main.html', controller: 'Main'})
```

What I want to do is have another URL that is `/main/details`.  This will be a div within `views/main.html` that I ONLY want appear when in this URL.  Then they can click a link that will take them back to /main but will hide the above div and show the other div.  How do I do this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do so.

If you don't need to share common stuff in your main template, just use two states (that are not nested) and map them to the urls `main` and `main/detail`. As long as the state names do not contain a dot, there is no nesting.

If you want to share a common template for main and insert stuff only for the detail state, you can use nesting. A pretty easy way would be to have an (abstract) main state with a placeholder div containing another ui-view directive and two nested (child) states `empty` and `with`. These child states then can provide the template that should be rendered into your main template. So for the `empty` one, the template can just be empty (must be something, not an empty string).

```
angular
  .module('main')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/main',
        abstract: true,
        template: '<div>some stuff possibly here: <div ui-view></div></div>'
      })
      .state('main.empty', {
        url: '',
        template: ' ' // cannot be empty string
      })
      .state('main.detail', {
        url: '/detail',
        template: '<div>the details</div>'
      });
  });
```

Be aware that your links then must target `main.empty` as state name, even if the url will just be `/main`.

A third option could also be to use named `ui-view`s and then control the content by assigning stuff to more than one view. But this one cannot provide  get pretty cumbersome as you then need to reference the first named `ui-view` for each and every other state and it also doesn't support the nested content you mentioned.